# Why have cookies on websites?

Tags: interface

What is the point of having cookies on websites? Is it to track you? because it is annoying sometimes when I go on websites and these cookies and options pop up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a rant

Comment: The need to get users to acknowledge cookies is something has to be done by law. Not something people wanted to implement everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: A cookie is a small data (max 4kb) that a web server saves to your computer via web browser. So it can track down any type of data that the website wants to track but with only your activity on their site, not elsewhere. Like: session, maintaining data across multiple visit, holding your shopping cart content, login details, and such...

It can be only retrieved by its own domain, for example www.sample.com cannot retrieve www.another.com cookie. But it can also be embedded with multiple domains and issue its own cookies.